# C++ for Deep Learning

Tags: python, library, c++, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am working about a project in Deep learning, it's about images classification but the problem is I should work with C++ and I don't have any idea about what libraries or software should I choose to work with.
PS. I have aleady experimant Python, tensorflow and keras.
Any Software recomendations or the equivalence of tensorflow and keras in C++.

Comment: Tensorflow is implemented in C++. See the [github repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/), there is a colorbar at the top of the file listing; if you expand it you'll see that the pink fraction represents 60% C++.